# Debug a Adobe AIR application which uses NativeProcess API to invoke a executable

Tags: apache-flex, air, flash-builder, festival

How can I find the return value of a executable which has been invoked by a AIR app using the [NativeProcess API](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/articles/interacting_with_native_process.html)? I am using Flash Builder 4. The following [c++ generated executable](http://festvox.org/festtut/notes/festtut_3.html#SEC8)

```
festival --tts "HelloSpeak.txt"
```

works fine on the Windows cmd line , but on invoking by the NativeProcess API like in the example article doesn't produce the desired result. I invoke the command with the arguments on a button click handler, but there is no TTS generated output. I don't have a clue of what is happening!!

Answer (score 0):

NativeProcess sends [exit](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcess.html#event%3aexit) event when finished, code is event.exitCode parameter.